# Show Folder Child Count in Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

Is it possible to show a folder child count in search results? The field is called folderchildcount.

I am using search against document sets and would like to show this column in the results?

I have tried defining the column and adding the xsl but I am getting an error that this field is not available.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SharePoint 2010, did you add the field to the list of columns on the Core Search Web Part?

The check list should be this:

- Is it a Managed Property? If not Fix that and do a full crawl.
- Is it defined as a column on the web part? If not add it to the XML.
- Are you referencing it in lowercase by name in the XSL? if not fix
  that.
- Do your fields actually have values? If not ensure you have good test
  data.

Comment: I have added <Column Name="FolderChildCount" /> to the fetched properties.  In addition I added <xsl:value-of select="folderchildcount" />   to the xsl.  When refreshing the search results I get error that field does not belong and there is error.

This is not a custom field but a out of the box field from sharepoint.

In terms of managed properties ows_FolderChildCount(Text) is not currently mapped.  Should it be mapped?

Comment: I also added ows_ItemChildCount mapped to testcount and included testcount in the columns and testcount in the xsl but i am not seeing any results.  Ideas?

Comment: Did you perform a full crawl after managing the property?

Comment: Yes, this resolved the issue after doing full crawl...ty

Comment: Great, any cahnges made to Managed Props have to have a full crawl before they will take effect.